# Copy the last value above in same column as active cell

Tags: excel

I'm looking to get the value of the last non-empty cell above an active cell in the same column. So if A34 is the active cell, it would search all cells above — i.e. A3:A13 for the last non-empty cell value and return it for use in a formula in A14.

So, if we have a column A of values spread out over many rows, like so:

### A3 = 1

### A4 = blank

### A5 =

### A6 = 2

### A7 = 3

### A8 =

### A9 = 4

### A10 =

### A11 = 5

### A12 =

### A13 =

### A14 = formula

So, A14 would have a formula that would check from the cell above until it finds the first non-empty cell in the same column and then adds '1' to that value, A14 would be 6 in this example returning column A11 value of 5, plus 1.

Is this possible with a formula?  The formula would copy down the column so we can fill values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the max function

`=MAX($A$1:A14)+1`